# OpenOffice Writer: preserve hyphen in text

Tags: command-line, copy-paste, openoffice-writer

I often use an editor like OpenOffice Writer to build documentation. My documentation is usually technical, and it often includes commands for the terminal.

When I format a command, I will indent the command by 1/2 inch and I will change the font to Times Roman or Times New Roman.

The editors replace a hyphen with a dash (I think its called an em-dash). So a command like:

```
ls -al
```

will fail when copy/pasted into a terminal due to the errant character.

The problem comes to light after performing a "Save as PDF". No matter what I do, the PDF always ends up with the wrong dash or hyphen (even if the OO document seems correct).

How do I distinguish text that include a hyphen so that the dash is unchanged?

Comment: Just semantics, but isn't it the other way around... replacing a hyphen with a dash? Have you checked the AutoCorrect options... Format > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options... (at least that is the menu item in LibreOffice). There are specific options for "Replace Dashes" as well as the usual "Replace" options. Although to be honest I don't think any of these options should be replacing a single hyphen with a dash (as in your example) - at least not in "LibreOffice".

Comment: The problem seems to be with "Export as PDF". They get munged in the final PDF. Let me get that added to the question.

Comment: FWIW, I tried the "Export as PDF" option in LibreOffice and this worked OK for me (the hyphens stayed as hyphens). There are a few options related to PDF creation but I can't see how these would specifically relate to hyphen/dash replacement though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typographically speaking, what you are typing is a hyphen or minus, not a dash, and what OpenOffice Writer is replacing the hyphen with is a dash, either an e-dash or an em-dash, depending on the context in which OpenOffice Writer sees your hyphen.

This is explained in the OpenOffice Writer under `replacement options`. Look in the index.

You can change this behavior from the menu, `Format` -> `AutoCorrect` -> `AutoCorrect Options...` and uncheck either or both of the `Replace dashes` boxes. You can also access the relevant help topic by clicking `Help` in this dialog.

Comment: Thank garyjohn. How do I inhibit it for a block of text like a command, while leaving it engaged for normal text?

Comment: I don't know how to inhibit it for certain regions. The two methods I've used to fix such dashes after they've been expanded from hyphens are: 1) delete the dashes and replace them by hyphen(s); 2) use `Find & Replace`, copying a dash from your text into the `Search for` box and typing hyphen(s) into the `Replace with` box.